# Table is divided into several sheets when imported in excel

Tags: export, list-manipulation, excel

i wanted to calculate a Student-t table with

```
m = 
Table[
  NSolve[
    Rationalize[
      Integrate[PDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, df], x], {x, -a, a}] == 
      Vertrauensintervall/100
    ], a, Reals
  ], 
  {df, 3, 30, 1}, 
  {Vertrauensintervall, {80, 90, 95, 98, 99, 99.73}}
]
```

but when I export it now to Excel, I get 30 sheets of those 6 values each :(

How can I tell Mathematica, to put it all in one sheet? (bonus would be formatted with just the value, without the a -> )

Comment: try `a/.First@NSolve`

Answer (score 3):

```
Export["matrix.csv", m[[All, All, 1, 1, 2]]]
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Your table can be generated much easier and considerably faster using

```
c = CDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, df], a] - 
    CDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, df], -a] // FullSimplify

m = Table[
      a /. FindRoot[c == Vertrauensintervall/100., {a, 0.1}], 
     {df, 3, 30, 1}, 
     {Vertrauensintervall, {80, 90, 95, 98, 99, 99.73}}
    ];
```

This exports to a single Excel sheet if you use:

```
Export["test.xls", m]
```

The CDF is the integrated PDF which Mathematica knows in algebraic form in the case of the `StudentTDistribution`. So, no need to integrate yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am a mathematica beginner, so it took me a while to even come up with my formula :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the built-in function `Quantile`  without having to use `Solve` or `FindRoot`.

```
m2 = Table[Quantile[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, df], (100 + Vertrauensintervall)/ 200.],
          {df, 3, 30, 1}, {Vertrauensintervall, {80, 90, 95, 98, 99, 99.73}}];
```

The result is identical to the one you get using the method suggested by @Sjoerd (to the deafult tolerance of 10^(-10) )

```
Chop[Norm[m - m2]] === 0
(* True *) 

Export["test.xls", m2]
```